# Unresizable table cells

Tags: html, css

I have table with text in each cell. I want to add a new text under some of them(As i did with that paragraph) but without moving "Text" and also without resizing the cell. How can i do this ?

HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table width="80%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
        <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>09:00</th>

        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>10:00</th>

        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text/td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>18:00</th>

        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text
        <p>REZERV</p></td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>19:00</th>

        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text
        <p>REZERV</p></td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>20:00</th>

         <td>Text</td>
         <td>Text</td>
         <td>Text</td>
         <td>Text</td>
         <td>Text</td>
         <td>Text</td>
         <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS Code:

```
body
{
    font-family: arial;
    background-image: url("back.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
th:first-child { /* CHANGE THE SIZE OF THE FIRST TH AND THE TD BELOW IT WILL FOLLOW... */
    width: 7%;
    font-weight: normal;
}
td
{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    outline: 3px solid #e3e3e3;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 30%;
}
tr:nth-child(even){
    background: rgba(200, 196, 196,0.9);
    color: white;
}
tr:nth-child(odd){
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255,0.9);
    color: grey;
}
td:after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    margin-top:50%;
}
th
{
    background: #666;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 20%;
}

td:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: lightblue;
    color: #666;
}
table tr:first-of-type {
    font-size:30px;
    font-style: italic;
}
p{
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/mh7qfr63/1/

Add vertical-align to make sure all tds content align to the top.

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Then if you want a certain top padding then add:

```
padding-top: 40px // or some other value
```

If you do not want your td to resize in height, you need to set explicitly height within the td. Since your width is percentage base, the width will change depending on your page's width.

Putting it together:

```
td
{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    outline: 3px solid #e3e3e3;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 30%;

    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 40px; // or other number
    height: 100px; // or other number
}
```